# Make fastlane less verbose

Tags: ruby, automation, command-line-interface, fastlane

Is there a way to configure (may be using the `Fastfile`, for example) or execute Fastlane in a less verbose way?

It currently prints a lot of information that generally blinds developers of warnings and also errors. The main problem is that it takes some time scrolling and searching for the yellow/red text among a lot of useless messages until you have a clue of what happened.

The default setup prints everything and surprisingly there is even a [`--verbose` mode](https://docs.fastlane.tools/plugins/plugins-troubleshooting/#use-the-verbose-mode) for the CLI, but I could not find anything that do the opposite, like for example a `--quiet` mode.

EDIT:

Bellow are some examples of output I would like to be able to suppress. Taking into account that I use a `Fastfile` from a git repo, `gym`, `match`, `cocoapods`, `get_version_number`, `increment_version_number` and several other actions

- `Installed Provisioning Profile` table
- All `git clone` and related from remote `Fastfile` download
- `get_version_number` and `increment_version_number` detailed outputs
- `legacy build system` info message
- All detailed outputs like match's *"Cloning remote git repo.."*, *"Successfully decrypted certificates repo"*, etc
- `gym`, `match`, fastlane and all other summaries printed
- All release notes from more up-to-date versions for `match`, `gym` and `fastlane` itself

Answer (score 16):

Did you check the fastlane documentation at https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/?
For some of them there are parameters to surpress output, for gym:

```
gym(
  ...
  silent: true,
  suppress_xcode_output: true,
  ...
)
```

Comment: Hey, I haven't noticed that. I will definitely check all actions used to make sure I can decrease the verboseness at least a bit (It is currently insane, so many logs!)

Comment: You could also check to update to latest fastlane version... maybe some stuff has changed in the meanwhile. My build has about 100-150 lines of output, but I didn't surpress everything.

Answer (score 0):

What are some examples of what you want to hide from the output? If you're talking about the `xcodebuild` output, it's being piped over to `xcpretty`, which does the rendering of the source files.

Comment: Hey Felix, I edited my question with some output examples I wish I could suppress. Thanks for the attention :)

Comment: No idea if it is even possible, should this be added as an issue/question os Fastlane's repo instead?

Comment: Hey @FelipeSabino, yeah, those are some great points, would you mind submitting an issue on GitHub, with your current output, so I can take a look?